# Finding a constant that does not depend on a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality

We consider a parameter $\nu>0$.
We note $b(\xi,x)=\nu(\xi^2+x^2)$ for all $\xi,x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I want to prove that there exists a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\int_0^{+\infty}e^{\Big(tanh(\frac{t}{2})-\frac{t}{2}\Big)b^2}dt\le \frac{c}{\nu^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$ for all $\xi,x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Please help me to do so. Thanks

Comment: for which variable want you to integrate,is it $t$?

Comment: yes the variable is  t

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{\Big(\tanh(\frac{t}{2})-\frac{t}{2}\Big)b^2}\,dt\ge
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{\Big(-\frac{t}{2}\Big)b^2}\,dt=\frac{2}{b^2}
$$
there is no such constant $c$ independent of $\xi,x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: and is it possible if we take $x^2+\xi^2\not=0$?

Comment: No, because $b$ is in the denominator, so if $\nu>0$ is fixed and $x^2+\xi^2\to0$ the rhs tends to infinity.

Comment: so in which conditions is it possible?

Comment: Which conditions and on that? As of now there is present $b$ in the rhs, so if it goes to zero no estimate from above is possible for the integral